# Remove All Text 2 Places After Decimal Place PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to scrape a products price from a page, however unfortunately it's not in a nice clean div so I'm having to clear all the other junk.

**Note**: I have looked at several examples however they all assume you only have  nice organised numbers in your variable, not raw HTML stuffed on the end.

**An example of the string my variable may hold:**

```
$2.87 <span>10% Off Sale</span>
```

I've played about with substr and sttrpos, read the manual and still can't figure it out on my own.

I want to just cut the string two digits after the first decimal place is found... No doubt it's extremely simple when you know how!

**What I want to end up with:**

```
$2.87
```

An example of the mess I've got myself into trying:

```
$whatIWant = substr($data, strrpos($data, ".") + 2);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<?php

$string = "$2.87 <span>10% Off Sale</span>";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/(\$\d+\.\d{2})/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "$2.87"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "$2.87"
}
```

For more info (why result is array etc.) you should check PHP manual on `preg_match()` function: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Excellent! Seems to do the job if I access it with $matches[0]. I've included a $ at the beginning of my example, this was incorrect, there is no symbol at the start, just a number. You're example doesn't work if the $ isn't there, could you adjust it to work without the $ at the start? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your pattern will also match `$2a87` by the way at the moment. Also is there a reason why you use `[0-9]` rather than `\d` for the second instance out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

The below should grab the matches for you;

```
$pattern = '/(\$\d+\.\d{2})/';
$string = '$2.87 <span>10% Off Sale</span>';

$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Outputs:

> Array ( [0] => $2.87 [1] => $2.87 )

Comment: This was also the correct answer. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is def better way to do this. For a start, assuming the html structure that you have above will always be the same, you could do something like:

```
$var = "$85.25 <span>10% Off Sale</span>";
$spl = explode("<", $var);
echo $spl[0];
```

Comment: Unfortunately the structure isn't always the same. The page is coded like a dog, the only reliable part is the fact every price has a decimal point followed by two digits so the first encountered decimal place is the most reliable way of approaching this. Thanks :)